# Computer program for polyhedral manifolds

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, computational-geometry

Suppose I have a 3-manifold obtained via face identifications of a polyhedron (e.g. the Poincaré sphere presented as a dodecahedron with opposite faces glued). Is there a program that exists for easily working with such manifolds? The only thing I really know how to do is to make a triangulation in Regina, but I'd like to avoid having to input a triangulation with an unholy number of simplices, if possible.

Comment: You could write a python script to generate the triangulation from the polyhedron identifications, then feed it to Snappy or Regina.    I think that's how several of the triangulations in Regina were generated -- for example, the Seifert-Weber dodecahedral space.  If your polyhedron is convex then the algorithm would be pretty straightforward: subdivide the faces then cone off in the polyhedron.

Comment: I think if you look around the Regina source code, you can find the python script to generate all the 3-manifold (triangulations) you get by gluing opposite faces of a dodecahedron.  That code could be readily adapted to essentially any convex polyhedron gluing.  It is ?likely? in the census code, but it might be in the utilities.

Comment: @RyanBudney I think this is what I’ll end up doing. I just wanted to check if anyone had made a program already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two standard answers to this question are [Snappy](https://snappy.computop.org/) and [Regina](https://regina-normal.github.io/). If you have a famous manifold, then it will likely be in one of the many censuses that come with the programs.  If you have a less-than-famous manifold, then find a surgery description of it and feed that to Snappy.